# Why is the kernel module cfg80211 also listed as a kernel process [cfg80211]?

Tags: wireless, kernel, modules

I do not understand why the kernel module `cfg80211` is also listed by `ps aux` as shown below:

```
$ ps aux | grep cfg80211
root 521 0.0 0.0 0 0 ? S< 16:09 0:00 [cfg80211]
```

Comment: Lekensteyn: You have edited my question and given it a slightly wrong meaning The command and its response given is not by lsmod but rather by '$ ps aux'.

Comment: Did izx's edits fix the problem in your post?

Answer (score 4):

It is the standard behavior of `ps` to list kernel threads, as these too are processes--just a different kind of process, because they run in [supervisor mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_mode#Supervisor_mode) (which some people call "kernel mode").

If you run `ps ax` (or `ps aux`) without piping its output to `grep`, you'll see a whole bunch of kernel modules listed first (and then probably some others interspersed with user processes, if they were started later).

For example, here's the first 10 lines of the current output of `ps ax` on my system:

```
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
    1 ?        Ss     0:03 /sbin/init
    2 ?        S      0:01 [kthreadd]
    3 ?        S     97:17 [ksoftirqd/0]
    6 ?        S      0:00 [migration/0]
    7 ?        S      0:24 [watchdog/0]
    8 ?        S      0:00 [migration/1]
   10 ?        S      6:06 [ksoftirqd/1]
   12 ?        S      0:18 [watchdog/1]
   13 ?        S<     0:00 [cpuset]
```

**`lsmod` will list loaded modules. `ps aux` will list current processes, including kernel processes associated with modules. These are different things, however. For example, a loaded kernel module might have any number of kernel processes associated with it (zero or more).**